# Image processing algorithm that can extract objects from an image into a black background

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm writing code in opencv python and I'm trying to process a Video frame-by-frame. My frames already have the requested objects in boxes I've been using the GrabCut algorithm to extract the objects out of the background but it is very inefficient even when I was using a sperate thread for it. (Dropped my Fps from 30 to 0.5) Any other algorthims out there that are less system demanding?

Comment: What's the size of your input frames? There are lighter alternatives to the GrabNCut method, but I'd need more info on your application to make a recommendation. Now, a very immediate solution is to downsize (maybe half, quarter the original size) the frame and perform the GrabNCut segmentation on this input. Get a segmentation mask and scale the results back to the original size.

Comment: The size of the frame is 360 x 640. How do you suggest doing that? I've tried it in the past and experienced issues with it. Edit: Thanks for the quick response btw